# Referencing a selected record in a datagrid from another datagrid

Tags: c#, asp.net, datagrid

I've got 2 datagrids on an ASPX form.  When I click on a record in datagrid #2, I want to reference a cell from datagrid #1.

So, currently when I select a record, I've got something like this in the code-behind:

```
protected void DataGrid_ClaimSearch_EditCommand(object source,
System.Web.UI.WebControls.DataGridCommandEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        string LPI_ID = e.Item.Cells[7].Text;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Response.Write(ex.Message);
    }        
}
```

Works perfectly.  Now, in my 2nd datagrid, I want to reference a cell in the first one, so I put this:

```
protected void DataGrid_ClaimDetail_EditCommand(object source,
System.Web.UI.WebControls.DataGridCommandEventArgs e)
{
    DataGridItem dgi = DataGrid_ClaimSearch.SelectedItem;
    string LPIStatus = dgi.Cells[1].Text;
}
```

This returns an error:

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

The line `string LPIStatus = dgi.Cells[1].Text;` is highlighted.

Any ideas how I can reference that first cell in my first datagrid when I click on my second datagrid?

Comment: try `string LPIStatus = dgi.Cells[1].ToString();`

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the `EditItemIndex` for `DataGrid_ClaimSearch` in the `DataGrid_ClaimSearch_EditCommand` method.

```
protected void DataGrid_ClaimSearch_EditCommand(object source, DataGridCommandEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        string LPI_ID = e.Item.Cells[7].Text;
        DataGrid_ClaimSearch.EditItemIndex = e.Item.ItemIndex;
        Response.Write(LPI_ID);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Response.Write(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

Now you can access the correct `DataGridItem` in the `DataGrid_ClaimDetail_EditCommand` method.

```
protected void DataGrid_ClaimDetail_EditCommand(object source, DataGridCommandEventArgs e)
{
    DataGridItem dgi = DataGrid_ClaimSearch.Items[DataGrid_ClaimSearch.EditItemIndex];
    string LPIStatus = dgi.Cells[1].Text;
    Response.Write(LPIStatus);
}
```